# arrow keys not working in Java application when using xmodmap

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, java

I've defined my keyboard mapping using xmodmap and it works beautifully with my browser and the rest of my software except java applications.

I tried switching the AWT_TOOLKIT to Mtoolkit instead but now instead of printing nothing, it is printing rectangles.

I would like to be able to use my keyboard shortcut in a Java application (ie <kbd>Super_L</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for Up, <kbd>Super_L</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for left etc.)

Please advise if you've encountered something similar.

PS: <kbd>Super_L</kbd> is the windows key

Comment: I don't have a solution with xmodmap, but I did find an incredibly awkward and painful solution using xkb input files: http://superuser.com/questions/558598/how-can-i-make-my-iso-level5-shift-arrow-keys-work-in-java-swing-guis/558628#558628

Comment: FYI this is no longer an issue in ubuntu 14 and most likely related to env vars such as  XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus

Comment: Might have come from a program that handled AWT events differently. This link https://github.com/chenkelmann/neo2-awt-hack might be useful in the future, but newer Java versions (and other UI libraries) don’t have this problem anymore. I had this problem too a few years ago.