# How can I get more control over the keyboard layout than XKB offers?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

I am starting to run up against [the](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00053400000000000000) [limits](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XKB#Keysyms_and_states) [of](https://superuser.com/questions/558598/how-can-i-make-my-iso-level5-shift-arrow-keys-work-in-java-swing-guis) [XKB](http://www.x.org/wiki/XKB), the keyboard subsystem of the X window system.

I would like to know if there is a way I can gain more flexibility. Here are examples of the kind of freedom I would like to obtain:

- When pressing `CapsLock+w`, generate `Ctrl+Right`.
- When pressing `f` `d` in rapid succession (but not slowly), generate `Escape`.
- When pressing `Ctrl+Space`, generate 4 spaces.

What are some ways I could obtain this? Is there a replacement for XKB? Should I simply modify XKB itself? Is there a way to get closer to full programmatic control of the keyboard behavior?

Comment: I hope those are just examples and not actual use cases... But if they are, I can't help but be curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employ an extensible input method framework such as [scim](http://enwp.org/Smart_Common_Input_Method) or [ibus](http://enwp.org/Intelligent_Input_Bus). The last one is possible out of the box by configuring the [m17n](http://www.nongnu.org/m17n/) backend, but I suspect the first two require you to program your input method.

Comment: Ah I had been wondering if an input method framework might get me there but I had been utterly at a loss where to begin. Do you know any references or examples to start with for my kind of unusual goals? Also, which do you recommend -- scim or ibus?

Comment: Join the IME mailing list for your distro: [opensuse-m17n](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-m17n/), [Debian pkg-ime-devel](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/pkg-ime-devel) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's relatively simple to accomplish some of what you want with [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/).

Answer (score 0):

daxim's suggestion of using an input method is a good one, particularly if you need to support non-Latin letters.

For my case, since I do not need to support non-Latin letters, I ended up [tapping directly into the Linux event handling system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581500/hook-into-linux-key-event-handling/27693340#27693340).

I ended up creating a [generic key remapping tool](https://github.com/ellbur/totalmapper) to accomplish this.