# In IntelliJ, can I make PageUp, PageDown move by smaller increments?

Tags: intellij-idea

A full screenfull is too fast for me to follow; I'd prefer maybe a half screenfull or ~10 lines.

Can this be done?

Comment: It might be easier to do this globally, if you want to consider this option.

Comment: @peanut_butter I would be happy to do this globally. How would I do that?

Comment: I've asked this a long time ago, it's so annoying on ubuntu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610249/intellij-idea-control-page-up-page-down-scroll-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a Windows machine, you can use a simple [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to remap page up and page down commands to scrolling 10 lines.

```
PgDn::Send {WHEEL_DOWN 3}
```

This (untested script) should send the simulate scrolling the wheel 3 times, which should scroll about 9 lines on default settings. You can easily set up a similar solution for page up, and alternatively send `DOWN` arrow commands, if the `WHEEL_DOWN` doesn't work as expected.

You can also make use of the [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive to only enable it for the active application.

If you are using another OS, I assume you can find some other hotkey/remap software that could more or less accomplish the same thing.

Comment: On Linux (which is what I am using) there may be a way to do this, too, but I am not sure how. The usual way of remapping keys through xkb makes it hard to produce multiple apparent keypresses in response to one actual keypress.

Comment: It seems that this may be doable via http://superuser.com/questions/613149/how-can-i-get-more-control-over-the-keyboard-layout-than-xkb-offers

Answer (score 2):

I had taken @yole's answer and implemented all of the actions he had described in a separate plugin:

> There is no way to control this through the settings. What you can do is write a plugin that performs scrolling in the way that you prefer. It's fairly easy: all you need to do is copy the existing 
>   PageUpAction/PageDownAction classes and the methods they call 
>   (EditorActionUtil.moveCaretPageUp/Down) to scroll by as much as you want.

This plugin implements new actions "Partial Page Up" and "Partial Page Down" which allow one to scroll a configurable size of screen definable in the usual IDEA settings dialog.

There's an installable version of the plugin in [official JetBrains repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11952-partial-navigation).

Comment: Sadly, this plugin it's not working anymore